# How to create a custom tag in app.config

Tags: c#, .net, xml, config

Afternoon,

After searching around and finding very little on this, I thought I will post the question I want answered.

As the question states I want to have a custom tag in a app.config file.

```
   <appSettings>
      <add key="exam" value="pp"/>
      <add key="exam" value="ss" />
   </appSettings>

<!-- This is the custom tag I want to have --!>
   <WebPoints>
      <host name="Main" value="URL" port="80" sslPort="633"></host>
   </WebPoints>
```

Of course when I run the code it complains that the config hasn't initialised correctly.

I gather what I want is a lot more work than it should be, but I like to know how much work there is.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a custom tag in web.config one can use [Custom Configuration sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2tw134k3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml;

namespace Samples.AspNet
{
    public class PageAppearanceSection : ConfigurationSection
    {
        // Create a "remoteOnly" attribute.
        [ConfigurationProperty("remoteOnly", DefaultValue = "false", IsRequired = false)]
        public Boolean RemoteOnly
        {
            get
            { 
                return (Boolean)this["remoteOnly"]; 
            }
            set
            { 
                this["remoteOnly"] = value; 
            }
        }

        // Create a "font" element.
        [ConfigurationProperty("font")]
        public FontElement Font
        {
            get
            { 
                return (FontElement)this["font"]; }
            set
            { this["font"] = value; }
        }

        // Create a "color element."
        [ConfigurationProperty("color")]
        public ColorElement Color
        {
            get
            {
                return (ColorElement)this["color"];
            }
            set
            { this["color"] = value; }
        }
    }

    // Define the "font" element
    // with "name" and "size" attributes.
    public class FontElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("name", DefaultValue="Arial", IsRequired = true)]
        [StringValidator(InvalidCharacters = "~!@#$%^&*()[]{}/;'\"|\\", MinLength = 1, MaxLength = 60)]
        public String Name
        {
            get
            {
                return (String)this["name"];
            }
            set
            {
                this["name"] = value;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("size", DefaultValue = "12", IsRequired = false)]
        [IntegerValidator(ExcludeRange = false, MaxValue = 24, MinValue = 6)]
        public int Size
        {
            get
            { return (int)this["size"]; }
            set
            { this["size"] = value; }
        }
    }

    // Define the "color" element 
    // with "background" and "foreground" attributes.
    public class ColorElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("background", DefaultValue = "FFFFFF", IsRequired = true)]
        [StringValidator(InvalidCharacters = "~!@#$%^&*()[]{}/;'\"|\\GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", MinLength = 6, MaxLength = 6)]
        public String Background
        {
            get
            {
                return (String)this["background"];
            }
            set
            {
                this["background"] = value;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("foreground", DefaultValue = "000000", IsRequired = true)]
        [StringValidator(InvalidCharacters = "~!@#$%^&*()[]{}/;'\"|\\GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", MinLength = 6, MaxLength = 6)]
        public String Foreground
        {
            get
            {
                return (String)this["foreground"];
            }
            set
            {
                this["foreground"] = value;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

web.config

```
<configuration>
<!-- Configuration section-handler declaration area. -->
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="pageAppearanceGroup">
      <section 
        name="pageAppearance" 
        type="Samples.AspNet.PageAppearanceSection" 
        allowLocation="true" 
        allowDefinition="Everywhere"
      />
    </sectionGroup>
      <!-- Other <section> and <sectionGroup> elements. -->
  </configSections>

  <!-- Configuration section settings area. -->

</configuration>
```